# Adding a color to an image under a mask with OpenCV (cv.add)

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV 3 to add a color to an image within a given mask.

Here's a simplified, reproducible version for an image with only one row with two pixels:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = np.array([[[0, 0, 0], [0,0,0]]], "uint8")
color = np.array([ 30, 50, 50], "uint8")
mask = np.array([[255, 0]], "uint8")
cv.add(img, color, img, mask=mask)
```

which produces the following error:

```
(-215:Assertion failed) type2 == 6 && (sz2.height == 1 || sz2.height == 4) in function 'cv::arithm_op'
```

I assume the reason for the error is that the color is neither an image with the same size as the original image, nor a scalar.

In fact, I get it to work if I use:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = np.array([[[0, 0, 0], [0,0,0]]], "uint8")
color = np.array([ 30, 50, 50], "uint8")
color_img = np.full_like(img, color) # create full image with a single color
mask = np.array([[255, 0]], "uint8")
cv.add(img, color_img, img, mask=mask)
```

but it seems wasteful to create `color_img` with identical pixels just to sum to `img`. Is there a way to sum the color directly to each pixel of `img`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it just using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 as cv 

img   = np.array([[[0, 0, 0], [0,0,0]]], dtype=np.uint8) 
color = np.array([ 30, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8) 
mask  = np.array([[255, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)

# Set pixels in "img" to "color" wherever "mask" > 0
img[mask>0] = color
```

**Result**

```
array([[[30, 50, 50],
        [ 0,  0,  0]]], dtype=uint8)
```